# Export users from keycloak - Timeout

Tags: timeout, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to get my users data with the Keycloak Admin Rest API, doing this GET request:

```
{realms}/users?max=-1
```

But, since there are too many users (~ 170.000) it fails due to timeout.

I've tried with Postman (with Timeout unlimited) and with the Python Requests library, without success.

How can I ignore that problem and get all of the users?

Comment: I tested to get 7000 users from local Keycloak. It just takes 3.54 seconds by Postman with 0 timeout(it is  Postman will wait for a response forever)
I think something wrong in your Keycloak.


How about divide small number of users and merge the user's data?

Like a just get each 1000 people upto 17K users.

{realms}/users?start=1&max=1000
{realms}/users?start=1001&max=1000
...
{realms}/users?start=16001&max=1000

Comment: Thanks! that's usefull. 

PS: I edited my question, since it was 170k and not 17k.

Comment: How long takes time in Postman just 1000 users?    GET {realms}/users?start=1&max=1000

Comment: @BenchVue right now i'm downloading 5000 users at 3-5 seconds. Nevertheless, I realized that the flag 'start' should be 'first'

Comment: Yes, you are right, I checked it [API documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/). If short time to get 3~5 seconds for 5K user, why don't use simple loop statement  to get all user to merge by your program. To merge then save file into single JSON file. It can be get all of users. I can help you if you want this approaches.

Comment: Actually I did that! so thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

try searching in your library for getting batch of users using offset and limit.

I use it for java so far, I've stopped at a batch of 1500 users so as not to load Keycloak with your big request.

But be careful with the default timeout rest-clients of 50-70 thousands+.